# Why Geting error while importing p12 file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, p12

I am have exported p12 file from another machine with empty password and trying to install it in other machine. But getting following error in another machine.

error - An error has occurred. Unable to import an item.The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.

Please click on below image link if not visible

[image]

Is there anything i am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: You cannnot export a p12 file with an empty password.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to combine two files including .certificate & key file and then export it and I think put password/ or not use it will work in both cases, before export to p.12
[image]
For reference I have attach screenshot.

[image: enter enter image description hereimage denter image description hereescription here]

[image]

Comment: thanks for help..Yes i am exporting like thid only..but hetting issue while importing

Comment: Then I think your downloaded certificate is not correct